# iPhone: Portrait to Landscape mode question?

Tags: iphone

I have one `UIButton`. I put one image on that. When I click on that image, I get one view.
In that view, there is one `UIButton` and `UIImageview`. How can I move this view from Portrait to Landscape mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you pop up a new view.  If your new view has its own UIViewController, you can specify that it `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` to whichever of these values you want:

```
typedef enum {
   UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait           = UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
   UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown = UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
   UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft      = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
   UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight     = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft
} UIInterfaceOrientation;
```